# Which file contain the git alias (ohmybash)?

Tags: linux, git, alias

The gau tool and gf tool are installed, but I am unable to use them due to using ohmybash, which has a git alias set for gau and gf. I want to unalias it right now, but I'm not sure which file the git alias is in.

I checked

`.bashrc`

`.profile`

`.zshrc`

`/etc/bashrc`

`/etc/profile`

[image]

Comment: Easiest option is probably to run `grep` on your `/etc` and home directory

Comment: It doesn't really matter. I assume there is some command in your `.bashrc` that sources a file that defines all the aliases; just make sure you execute `unalias gau gf` *after* this command.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)